# How to download membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

I have the latest version of ASP.NET and Visual Studio 2012, but I don't know where to download the membership provider so that I can create a user system for an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET comes with a few web membership providers built-in. Including for instance the `SqlMembershipProvider` and `WindowsMembershipProvider`. The former is what you'll usually want to use on a public website.

Or were you looking for a specific one that's not built-in?

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for whatever is the "new" thing. I haven't used .NET in a couple of years and I vaguely remember downloading some asp_reg file and having like 11 tables installed in SQL Server.

Comment: Those all come with the installation (as long as you have a "full" .NET installation and not the "client profile" which doesn't come with web stuff IIRC)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Not sure why my question got a down-vote though!